# Not receiving data from BLE device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm here again.
So, long story short: in my app I'm trying to receive datas from my BLE device (tickr heart rate monitor: [that](http://eu.wahoofitness.com/instructions/tickr)) with the help of Android Samples ([that](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/project.html)). 
But... I'm not receiving datas from my device! I'm able to get the Characteristics and the Descriptor, but... nothing more. I simply.. *miss the point*.
Here's my code:

```
private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
private ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> mGattCharacteristics =
        new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic;
public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";
private static final int CONNECTED_ID = 1;
private String mDeviceName;
private String mDeviceAddress;
private boolean mConnected = false;
BluetoothGatt btGatt;
BluetoothGattCharacteristic btGattCharacteristic;
 private List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
    @InjectView(R.id.hrate) public TextView hRate;
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "gatt connected");
            mConnected = true;
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "gatt disconnected");
            hRate.setText("0");
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "service discovered");
            returnServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "data available");
            displayHR(intent.getExtras().getString(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            onDestroy();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        Log.i("", "i'm connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

@OnClick({R.id.button_start, R.id.button_pause, R.id.button_stop})
public void OnSession(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.button_start:
            if(first) {
                first=false;
                onBLE();
            }
            else {
                startRun();
                if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
                    getActivity().registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
                    final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
                }
            }
            break;
}
public Dialog onBLE(){
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Vuoi utilizzare un device?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Sì", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(intent), CONNECTED_ID);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    hRate.setText("N.D.");
                    startRun();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    android.app.AlertDialog ble = builder.create();
    ble.show();
    return null;
}

public void startRun(){
    timeAtStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updated, 0);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONNECTED_ID){
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mDeviceName = data.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
            mDeviceAddress = data.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            Log.i("", mDeviceAddress+" "+mDeviceName);
            connect();
            startRun();
        }

    }
}
public void connect(){
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BluetoothLeService.class);
    getActivity().bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, getActivity().BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
public void displayHR(String arg){
    if(arg != null){
        hRate.setText(arg);
    }
}
private void returnServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;

    for (BluetoothGattService service : gattServices) {
        gattCharacteristics=service.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : service.getCharacteristics()) {
            if (characteristic.getUuid().toString().compareTo(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT) == 0)
                btGattCharacteristic = characteristic;

        }
    }
    if ((btGattCharacteristic.getProperties() | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
        if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
            mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
        }
        mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(btGattCharacteristic);
    }

    if ((btGattCharacteristic.getProperties() | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
        mNotifyCharacteristic = btGattCharacteristic;
        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(btGattCharacteristic, true);

    }
}

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}
```

here's my logcat:

```
09-25 11:38:05.975  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
09-25 11:38:06.092  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 3% free 9444K/9716K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
09-25 11:38:06.147  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
09-25 11:38:07.194  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onScanResult() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 RSSI=-61
09-25 11:38:07.842  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
09-25 11:38:07.921  25709-25709/apheniti.prova I/﹕ DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 TICKR
09-25 11:38:08.006  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ connect() - device: DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4, auto: false
09-25 11:38:08.006  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ registerApp()
09-25 11:38:08.006  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ registerApp() - UUID=e8dfe101-58d1-4c04-bc3b-f1983e19b468
09-25 11:38:08.014  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
09-25 11:38:08.014  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothLeService﹕ Trying to create a new connection.
09-25 11:38:08.014  25709-25709/apheniti.prova I/﹕ i'm connected
09-25 11:38:08.483  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=4 device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4
09-25 11:38:08.491  25709-25723/apheniti.prova I/BluetoothLeService﹕ Connected to GATT server.
09-25 11:38:08.491  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ discoverServices() - device: DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4
09-25 11:38:08.491  25709-25723/apheniti.prova I/BluetoothLeService﹕ Attempting to start service discovery:true
09-25 11:38:08.491  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.499  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.499  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.499  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.506  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.506  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=a026ee01-0a7d-4ab3-97fa-f1500f9feb8b
09-25 11:38:08.506  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetService() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=a026ee03-0a7d-4ab3-97fa-f1500f9feb8b
09-25 11:38:08.506  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.514  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.514  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.530  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.530  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.538  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.546  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.546  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.546  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.553  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.561  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=a026e002-0a7d-4ab3-97fa-f1500f9feb8b
09-25 11:38:08.561  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=a026e004-0a7d-4ab3-97fa-f1500f9feb8b
09-25 11:38:08.561  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetCharacteristic() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=a026e00a-0a7d-4ab3-97fa-f1500f9feb8b
09-25 11:38:08.569  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetDescriptor() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.569  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetDescriptor() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.577  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetDescriptor() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.585  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetDescriptor() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.585  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetDescriptor() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.600  25709-25723/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onGetDescriptor() - Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
09-25 11:38:08.600  25709-25722/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onSearchComplete() = Device=DA:E1:DD:95:BB:D4 Status=0
09-25 11:38:09.624  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 441K, 5% free 9514K/9992K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
09-25 11:38:11.944  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 485K, 6% free 9542K/10064K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
09-25 11:38:14.772  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 490K, 6% free 9566K/10092K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
09-25 11:38:15.991  25709-25709/apheniti.prova D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(btGattCharacteristic)` call but no `onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)` callback to receive the value. It's part of a [BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html).

My understanding of the process is that first you find a `BluetoothDevice` one way or another -- probably by a BLE scan. You identify it e.g. by its name (with `device.getName()`) or by the advertising data and connect to it with `device.connectGatt(context, false/true, gattCallback)`.

Then in your callback you receive the connection status in `onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)`. If the state is `BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED` you can discover the services with `gatt.discoverServices()`. This will trigger `onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)` where you'll get the available services by `gatt.getServices()` and identify the correct service by its UUID and get its characteristics by `service.getCharacteristics()` and again identify the correct characteristic by its UUID.

You will then read the characteristic with `gatt.readCharacteristic(                                             service.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID))`. This then triggers the `onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)` callback. Here you'll check which characteristic you received (as things are asynchonous) with `characteristic.getUuid()` and read its String value with `characteristic.getStringValue(0)` or Float value with `getFloatValue(0)` etc. depending on the data type.

It can be confusing because of the chain of asynchronous operations. However there's nice sample code for both the server and the client in [here](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples) and more specifically the client code is [in this file](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/blob/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothgattperipheral/ClientActivity.java). They are related to [this excellent video about BLE on Android](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1697/android_lollipop_bluetooth_andevcon) by NewCircle which also explains the code a little bit.

The Android sample you are referring to might be a bit confusing as it also involves Activity/Service interaction and isn't purely about Bluetooth LE. Better to have a look the NewCircle video and sample project perhaps...

Comment: Oh, I forgot about thanking you! My problem was that I did an absurd mess between different methods, so my app did not retrieve data as it was supposed to be. Your suggestion was soooo utile! I used that site for comprehend the subject from the beginning and... it was awfully simple to me that way. Thank you again!