# ANDROID: Bluetooth low energy read continuously

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'd like to log continuously data from bluetooth device, such as an external accelerometer. In this step I want to do it without a scan activity, just hardcoding all the necessary ids (MAC ADDRESS, UUIDs etc.). How can I perform it? What are the right steps in the various callbacks?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(SENSORTAG_ADDRESS );
    Log.i(BLE_TEST_TAG, "Connecting to: "+device.getName());
    /**
     * Make a connection with the device using the special LE-specific
     * connectGatt() method, passing in a callback fot GATT events.
     * The booelan param indicates whether to automatically connect
     * to the BLE device as soon as possible as it becomes available.
     */
    mConnectedGatt = device.connectGatt(this,true, bluetoothGattCallback);
}

private BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

@Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        gatt.discoverServices();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(ST_ACCELEROMETER_UUID_SERVICE));
        /** Enable accelerometer */
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic config = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(ST_ACC_UUID_CONFIG));
        config.setValue(new byte[]{0x01});
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(config);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        Integer x = characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
        Integer y = characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
        Integer z = -1 * characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2);
        double scaledX = x / 64.0;
        double scaledY = y / 64.0;
        double scaledZ = z / 64.0;
        final float[] values = new float[3];
        values[0] = (float) scaledX;
        values[1] = (float) scaledY;
        values[2] = (float) scaledZ;
        Log.i(BLE_TEST_TAG, String.valueOf(scaledX)+" - "+String.valueOf(scaledY)+" - "+String.valueOf(scaledZ));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
         //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        //TODO
    }

};
```

Comment: Does the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779643/not-receiving-data-from-ble-device/32955582#32955582) and the linked external resources help? And here's the Android documentation [talking about subscribing to notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification) to receive updated values when they change.

Comment: Yes it helps Markus, but I'd like to receive sensor data countinuously and it seems it works just once. I don't understand how to achieve this! Thank you!

Comment: You can use the `setCharacteristicNotification()` method to "subscribe to notifications" so that the `onCharacteristicChanged()` callback method is triggered whenever there's a new value for the characteristic. (As shown in the Android documentation)

Comment: Yes I'm doing it, but  onCharacteristicChanged() is never called.

Comment: I've edited the source code to better explain what I'm trying to do. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, the code inside onCharacteristicRead is inside onCharacteristicChanged.