# Android and BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a project in which I want to receive the data(, separated value"only two values") from BLE server. my first question is I write the code for connection but I din't connect with it. and second how to read this comma separated value. and this comma separated value will come from arduino to BLE server and from BLE server the communication will be done between both. Code is Below.

IDs

```
#define SERVICE_UUID   "ab0828b1-198e-4351-b779-901fa0e0371e"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX  "4ac8a682-9736-4e5d-932b-e9b31405049c"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX  "0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91"
```

code

```
package com.grng.rthr;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import com.grng.rthr.main.core.viewmodel.MainViewModel;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.grng.rthr.main.BackAwareApplication;
import com.grng.rthr.main.core.viewmodel.MainViewModel;
import com.grng.rthr.main.ui.fragment.atWork.ModeFragment;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    // GUI Components
    private TextView mBluetoothStatus;
    private MainViewModel viewModel;
    private TextView mReadBuffer;
    private Button mScanBtn;
    private Button mOffBtn;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBTAdapter;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mBTArrayAdapter;
    private ListView mDevicesListView;

    private final String TAG = BluetoothActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Handler mHandler; // Our main handler that will receive callback notifications
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread; // bluetooth background worker thread to send and receive data
    private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket = null; // bi-directional client-to-client data path

    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("ab0828b1-198e-4351-b779-901fa0e0371e"); // "random" unique identifier


    // #defines for identifying shared types between calling functions
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1; // used to identify adding bluetooth names
    private final static int MESSAGE_READ = 2; // used in bluetooth handler to identify message update
    private final static int CONNECTING_STATUS = 3; // used in bluetooth handler to identify message status



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);


//        setTitle("Belt Monitoring");
        setTitle("Belt Monitoring");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_btn);


        mBluetoothStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bluetoothStatus);
        mReadBuffer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readBuffer);
        mScanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
        mOffBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.off);

        mBTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get a handle on the bluetooth radio

        mDevicesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.devicesListView);
        mDevicesListView.setAdapter(mBTArrayAdapter); // assign model to view
        mDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        bluetoothOn();

        // Ask for location permission if not already allowed
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);


        mHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                    String readMessage = null;
                    try {
                        readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mReadBuffer.setText(readMessage);
                }

                if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
                    if(msg.arg1 == 1)
                        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connected to Device: " + (String)(msg.obj));
                    else
                        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        };

        if (mBTArrayAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            mBluetoothStatus.setText("Status: Bluetooth not found");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth device not found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {


            mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bluetoothScan(v);
                }


            });

            mOffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    bluetoothOff(v);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void bluetoothOn(){
        if (!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth enabled");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void bluetoothScan(View view){



        mBTArrayAdapter.clear();
        mPairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // put it's one to the adapter
            for (BluetoothDevice device : mPairedDevices)
                mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show Paired Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        discovering();


    }


    private void discovering(){

        if(mBTAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Discovery stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                mBTArrayAdapter.clear(); // clear items
                mBTAdapter.startDiscovery();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                registerReceiver(blReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    // Enter here after user selects "yes" or "no" to enabling radio
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent Data){
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // The user picked a contact.
                // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.
                mBluetoothStatus.setText("Enabled");
            }
            else
                mBluetoothStatus.setText("Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void bluetoothOff(View view){
        mBTAdapter.disable(); // turn off
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Bluetooth disabled");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    final BroadcastReceiver blReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name to the list
                mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                mBTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };


    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

            if(!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connecting...");
            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            final String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
            final String name = info.substring(0,info.length() - 17);

            // Spawn a new thread to avoid blocking the GUI one
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    boolean fail = false;

                    BluetoothDevice device = mBTAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                    try {
                        mBTSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        fail = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
                    try {
                        mBTSocket.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        try {
                            fail = true;
                            mBTSocket.close();
                            mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, -1, -1)
                                    .sendToTarget();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            //insert code to deal with this
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    if(fail == false) {
                        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mBTSocket);
                        mConnectedThread.start();

                        mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 1, -1, name)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    };

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        try {
            final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", UUID.class);
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, BTMODULEUUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.available();
                    if(bytes != 0) {
                        buffer = new byte[1024];
                        SystemClock.sleep(100); //pause and wait for rest of data. Adjust this depending on your sending speed.
                        bytes = mmInStream.available(); // how many bytes are ready to be read?
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes); // record how many bytes we actually read
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget(); // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy? Isn't `BluetoothSocket` used with classic Bluetooth? If the other end is actually a BLE device then it's a "GATT server" and the communication happens in a completely different way. There's the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) to read and maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779643/not-receiving-data-from-ble-device/32955582#32955582) can be useful.

Comment: Okay. It's mean that I can't get data from BLE if I use Classic Bluetooth.